# What is the Flatpak repo for the AppCenter?

Tags: appcenter

[The AppCenter is a flatpak repo](https://blog.elementary.io/elementary-appcenter-flatpak/), so it should be possible (in theory) to add the AppCenter Flatpak repo to an OS other than elementary. I've been searching for a while but haven't found anything relevant.

So, can I have a `.flatpakrepo` for the appcenter?

Apologies if this is the wrong place to ask.

Answer (score 0):

> We’ll be providing our own hosted and curated Flatpak repo for AppCenter ...

I don't think this is ready/public yet (-> We *will*). I've only installed Flatpaks so far from flathub on elementary.

Comment: yes, but it was written in the past. all the things on the appcenter site are in the format of `com.github.dev.appname`. That's the flatpak format

Comment: That format is called reverse domain name notation, and it is not flatpak specific.